# $\forall\varepsilon>0,|Z_{n}-Z|<\varepsilon\text{ a.a.}$

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

> **Claim**: Let $Z$, $Z_{1}$, $Z_{2}$, $\dots$ be random variables. Suppose $P(|Z_{n}-Z|\geq\varepsilon\text{ i.o.})=0$ for each $\varepsilon>0$. Then $P(Z_{n}\to Z)=1$.
>
> **Proof**: $P(Z_{n}\to Z)=P(\forall\varepsilon>0,|Z_{n}-Z|<\varepsilon\text{ a.a.})=\cdots$

The argument of $P$ is a set. How do I interpret "$\forall\varepsilon>0,|Z_{n}-Z|<\varepsilon\text{ a.a.}$" as a set?

Comment: What does your abbreviation a.a. mean?

Comment: The book abbreviates **almost always** as a.a., which is the $\liminf$ of a collection of sets.

Comment: Okay: I'm used to this being "evt." for eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$"\forall \varepsilon>0, |Z_n-Z|<\varepsilon a.a."$ is really the set

$$
\cap_{\varepsilon>0} \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=N}^{\infty} (|Z_n-Z|\leq \varepsilon)=
\cap_{m=1}^{\infty} \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=N}^{\infty} (|Z_n-Z|\leq \frac{1}{m}), $$

with the latter rewriting to emphasise that this *is*, in fact, a measurable set.